# Using more than 9 unnamed captures in Ruby Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a long string formatted like a log entry and am looking to get several captures from it and store them in different variables.

I know Ruby stores the first 9 captures into the variables $1...$9, does it also store other captures in $10...$99?

If not what would be a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can't you use named captures?

Comment: Why do you limit it to `99`? I think it would be more likely to be either not limited or limited to one digit rather than being limited to two digits. Limit to two digits has less basis than limit to one digit.

Comment: no particular reason. I tried to find out myself (didn't really think to use the interpreter) and came across a page that compared different flavors(lost the link) and what features they allowed.  One of the rows had $10-$99 but it didn't have info on ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does.

```
"a2c4d7l4l0j4h9h7".gsub(/(\w)(\d)(\w)(\d)(\w)(\d)(\w)(\d)(\w)(\d)(\w)(\d)(\w)(\d)(\w)(\d)/) do
  $12
end
#=> "4"
```

Answer (score 8):

`String#match` returns [`MatchData`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html) object which holds an array of captures.

```
m = Regexp.new('(.)' * 20).match('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
m[12]
# => "r"
```

Although $12 also works:

```
> $12
# => "r"
```